# React router creates two exact same components on route change, how to reuse same component across two routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've made a quick test that looks like this :

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/foo" render={ () => <TestComponent key="test" data="1" /> } />
    <Route path="/bar" render={ () => <TestComponent key="test" data="2" /> } />
  </switch
</Router>
```

Where the `TestComponent` looks like this :

```
const TestComponent = withRouter(({ history, data }) => {
   const [ value, setValue ] = useState(null);
   const loading = !value;

   useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
         setValue(data);
         history.push('/bar');
      }, 1000 );
   }, [ data ]);

   console.log("**VAL", data, value);

   return <div>
      { data } / { loading ? "LOADING" : value }
   </div>;
});
```

So, when I hit the route `/foo`, the component loads, wait a second, then redirect to the other route using the same component (albeit a different instance).

The debug shows

```
**VAL 1 null
**VAL 1 1
**VAL 2 null          // <-- expected : VAL 2 1
**VAL 2 2
**VAL 2 2
```

I would've expected React to see that both are the same component and not create a different instance. How can I have the same component respond to two different routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one `Route` component have multiple paths, so multiple paths will result in the same component. More specifically the `path` prop of `Route` can take a string or string array. See docs here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string

Then you can use one of the [`react-router` hooks](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) to determine which route you are on and render whatever differences you need based on that. Alternatively, you could use [URL Parameters](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) or [Query Parameters](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters).

Comment: See, the components I use have transition effects for various states, so your solution works only in a few cases. The other cases are as if the page is completely reloaded, skipping transitions and all. I guess I can settle for this at the moment, but it's not ideal.

Comment: If you'd like to flesh out these other cases a little more, I'm not sure I follow, but would be happy to chat about it. Otherwise, glad to offer at least some assistance.

Comment: You could also have the `Switch` exist inside of `TestComponent` if most of `TestComponent` is shared between the two routes.

Comment: A few routes have a sidepanel that slides in, and this panel remains visible on routes that are "common", but as soon as I set a route with a different side panel, the panel does not slide out, but disappears completely, then the new one slides in. It's ugly. I'll try to figure out a way for this, but it seems `react-router` has no way of waiting before unmounting routes...

Comment: the sidepanel slides in on mount? Could you just keep track of whether or not it's open or not, so that when you go to the new page, it's already open?

my personal opinion is that it should either be open or closed at start, and not animate unless a user changes the state. but you do you of course.